# 404 when rendering 3D model in django template three.js

Tags: javascript, django, 3d

So I was following this [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGokKxJ8D2c) on how to render a 3d object. Nothing gets loaded on my webpage because it throws a 404 error on the location of the model. Now I don't know where to place this 3d model because of the django structure. So my structure is the following.

```
home
   templates/home
      home.html <--- here I import my 3d.js script
theme
   static
      js
         3d.js
```

The script is loaded in correctly so there is no problem there, I just struggle to find where to place my models directory with the 3d models in.
My 3d.js looks like this.

```
import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/build/three.module.js";
import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
import { GLTFLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.129.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

let mouseX = window.innerWidth / 2;
let mouseY = window.innerHeight / 2;

let object;
let controls;
let objToRender = 'eye';

const loader = new GLTFLoader();
var loc = window.location.pathname;
var dir = loc.substring(0, loc.lastIndexOf('/'));
console.log(loc);

loader.load(
    `/models/${objToRender}/scene.gltf`,
    function (gltf) {
        object = gltf.scene;
        scene.add(object);
        console.log('Model loaded successfully:', object);
    },
    function (xhr) {
        if (xhr.total !== undefined) {
            console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
        }
    },
    function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        console.log('An error happened');
    }
);


const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

document.getElementById('3d-container').appendChild(renderer.domElement);

camera.position.z = objToRender === 'dino' ? 5 : 10;

const topLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
topLight.position.set(500, 500, 500);
topLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(topLight);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x333333, objToRender === 'dino' ? 0.5 : 1);
scene.add(ambientLight);

if (objToRender === 'dino') {
    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    if (object && objToRender === 'eye') {
        object.rotation.y = -3 + mouseX / window.innerWidth * 3;
        object.rotation.x = -1.2 + mouseY * 2.5 / window.innerHeight;
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);    
});

document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
}    

animate();
```

This is the 404 error: `http://localhost:8001/models/eye/scene.gltf`
I look forward to everyone's thoughts and help.

### EDIT

I tried putting the models folder under /home/templates/home/models already and also in /theme/models

Comment: Put the model in yout staticfiles directory and reference it from there. You can do something like `<script>window.my3dmodelURL = '{% static "your/path/to/scene.gltf" %}'</script>`

Comment: It works, Instead of refering to a js file i just put it in the html code